# N-G Bonding Jumper problem

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, grounding-and-bonding, ground

I found out that my meter base has an N-G Bonding Jumper but also there is one in my service equipment main panel and also another one in the service panel for all the backyard lighting and equipment which bonding should I take out?

Comment: Do you have a breaker in your meter base? Is your main panel equipped with a single main breaker, multiple (rule of 6) disconnecting means, or no disconnecting means?  Is the backyard lighting and equipment panel controlled by a single breaker (other than the main breaker if present) in the main panel?

Comment: Is there a grounding conductor between all the points, or is it all three wire feeders?

Comment: Some utilities are now requiring a bond in the meter base.

Comment: Pictures would be great

Comment: No there's no breaker in the meter base, Yes the Main Panel that's inside the house has a 200 amps 240 volts main breaker, the outside panel for the backyard its powered straight from the meter as well as the inside main panel but in the backyard panel they put a 60 amps 240 volts side breaker acting as a main breaker (not sure if I explain myself).

Comment: Also the connection between the Ground cable and the Neutral cable in the Meter base is thru the frame not in the Main Panel where the Right Bus Bar has the Neutral cable coming in and the left Bus Bar has the Ground cable coming in but the two bus bars are bridge with a bonding jumper.

Comment: No there's no grounding conductor between all the points, actually, the main grounding wire connected to the Grounding Rod goes to the Main inside Panel. and the bonding between the Neutral and the Ground inside the Meter base is Thru the Meter Metal Frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bonding jumper should always occur at the first means of disconnect. Whether it is at the panel with a main breaker or a remote enclosed breaker. After that every panel or breaker should have an isolated neutral bus and a separate grounding bus. So you subpanel should be corrected.

The meter is covered under NEC Article 90.2(B)(5) a. Which basically states that the NEC does not cover property owned or leased from the electric utility and includes you meter and meter base. So they have there own codes and we simply do what they have requested.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can bond the neutral to ground at the service drop, in the meter can, or in the service equipment. If you remove the neutral bonding in this system, you'll have to provide a ground-fault current path. This means installing a separate grounding conductor from the bonding location, to all other devices/outlets/enclosures fed by the service. You **cannot** simply remove the bonding jumper in the panel, otherwise the system will be ungrounded from that point on.

Comment: Thank you Tester101; I know, I don't want to remove the bonding from all the points but I also know that the bonding should be only in one place not in all the parts. What I don't know is what's the best point to leave it on